# Not Kissing our Tzitzis on Tisha Bav in Shacharis

Tags: tzitzis, tisha-bav, kissing

Why do we not Kiss our Tzitzis on Tisha Bav by Boroch Sheamar and Kriyas Shemah as we do the rest of the year?

Comment: We don't kiss them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the same reason that we don't wear a tallis during Shacharis on Tish'a Be'av: it's based on the Targum to Lam. 2:17, which renders בִּצַּע אֶמְרָתוֹ as בִּזַּע פּוּרְפִירָא דִילֵיהּ - He rent His royal robes. So even though we wear the tallis katan, we "downgrade" it by not acknowledging it as we usually do.

Comment: Is there any real source for not kissing tzitzis on Tisha B'av, or is it just the "minhag ha'olam"?

Comment: Thats what I was asking I have a hunch is Kabbalistic

Comment: It is not Kabbalistic.  The Arizal wore Talit and Tefillin as normal during Tisha B'Av.  It is covered in Sha'ar HaKavvanot 89c, the RaShaSh(R' Shalom Sharabi) speaks about it at length in Nahar Shalom in three separate places, 13a, 24a, 39c.  The Ben Ish Hai also is for wearing Talit and Tefilin(and thus kissing the tzitzit) Ben Ish Hai, year 1 Devarim 25.  Finally the most detailed source is Rav Ovadyah Hedayyah's Deah V'Haskeil 8:6.  Ultimately I believe this is simply an Ashkenazi custom.  Sephardi poskim follow the Mekubalim who hold opposite.

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know why we do it would you?

Comment: @mekubal Harav Yaakov Hillel Shelit"a has a whole Teshuva on why you should.